# Async task and downloading progress in notification bar not working when app is destroyed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am downloading some images using async task and all thing is working fine, Then Idea came up into my mind to show the download progress in the notification area so I used this tutorial and got 100 percent success. See this link I think this is a nice [link](http://javatechig.com/android/progress-notification-in-android-example) for the beginners.

But then I tested somethings and gets extremely failed in it these are as under:

**This is what I observed**

1> Async task stops working when I close the app using task manager or when I pragmatically do this.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The point for using this code is to test either my `AsyncTask` is working in background or not.

2> I want that if my app is destroyed the download process should keep on going and keep updating the download progress in the notification bar and yes I want to show the button in the notification that would be used to stop the download and open the activity.

Please tell me how can I achieve these two points. I have noticed the download process of play store app and it does exactly the same as I wanted.

Please help me on these two points.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to do that. Service has a different lifecycle than activity with UI that ensures it will continue working even if the UI was destroyed. In fact this is what services are all about, long running operations that are not directly tie to the UI.

Services can ofcourse publish notifications to the bar and receive inputs from it as well

Comment: can you please tell me what if I use the asynctask in the service ?

Comment: It will work great. A service may have an Asynctask object.

Comment: good , so what you would suggest , my inner aysnc class , i should cut paste the same code here in service ?

Comment: my that async class is in that activity which is launching the asyc and start to download

Comment: In theory, if you wrote a clean well encapsulated code. if you cut and paste it should work. There is no reason why not.

Comment: Oh man I forget to ask the main thing , and that is , what if i run the service and go to task manager and kill my app  ? what should happen ? service will stop ?

Comment: You can control that and make sure it will not stop. Everything there is to know about services is in the original link at the begining of my answer.

Comment: I know but I have read this , and its talk abotu sticky service , intent service I do not understand what does it mean. ? i just wanted to make an service  which not be killed when app is killed

Answer (score 0):

With the code given, you are not testing if your AsyncTask is able to run in Background. You are trying to let the AsyncTask run without your App. Hm. That can't work, unless your AsyncTask is part of another program.

With using this line

```
    System.exit(0);
```

your process is destroyed, and all threads of it. This is not the same as just closing the user interface.
You should instead use

```
yourActivity.finish()
```

Then it should work fine.

***Update***

If you need the download to keep loading even if the app is destroyed by e.g. force close, you will need this:

1. Implement a sticky service, that registers for an Intent, say "example.com.START_DOWNLOAD", put the URI as an extra into this Intent. The service may be started by this intent or on system boot - whatever fits better for your needs.
2. Your app sends this Intent instead of creating the AsyncTask on its own.
3. Your service and your activity have to be separate packages; if the app is closed, this has no effect on your download.

Please mind that a service may crash or be forced to close, too. Even a sticky service can have this of cause, but it will be restarted directly (up to two restarts, after that it is judged to be corrupt). So, if the download shall go on, you must implement a "resume download" functionality. If the download is not that big in size, it may be valid just to restart the download(s).

Comment: i know it works fine with your suggested way , I already tried , but what if I want  the async to run and complete its task even the app is destroyed

Comment: can you answer me please ?

Comment: Your app may be destroyed by the OS (which is not likely to be a frequent trouble) or by user action (choosing force close in settings or reboot/shut down of the phone) - not to mention an app bug. If you want to cover these situations, you should consider to implement a resume functionality. (Save each arriving data to a tmp file and resume at that point, if the running download was interrupted.)

Comment: but if you take a look to the google play app download , if you force close the app , the download process still goes on and updates your notification progress , and if you click to there it takes you back to app , and there you can stop the downloading , So I want to achieve same functionality.

Comment: Well, my answer and that of Eden are somehow the same, and a combination of this is what you might need. I change my answer to reflect that.